# How can I display a bootstrap dropdown in a fixed height container with overflow hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created an expandable toolbar that also contains a bootstrap dropdown component. I need this toolbar to be a fixed height, with all components that extend beyond the toolbar size to be hidden (except for popups). So I have applied `overflow:hidden` to that toolbar container. However, this has the undesired effect of hiding part of the dropdown when it is expanded. Is there a way that I can prevent this dropdown from getting clipped?

My main concern is the vertical clipping, not the horizontal clipping.

I have tried adjusting the `z-index` as shown in the example without success.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
<div style='position:absolute;top:12px;left:12px;width:300px;height:100px;border:solid 1px #888;overflow:hidden;'>
<div class="input-group" style='z-index:9998;'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style='z-index:9999;'>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. Expandable toolbar here. 
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The example provided is just a minimal example. Below shows screenshots of the real toolbar, to provide context.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment

> Move the menu outside the Expandable toolbar and wrap both with an
> outer div so the menu will not be clipped by the hidden overflow of
> the toolbar

**Update:** Added `data-boundary="viewport"` so that the menu does not obstruct the button (use "Full Page" to see effect).

**Update 2:** Reworked based on additional input.  I'm using flex containers to mimic your layout. since the toolbar is expandable I'm toggling `overflow` accordingly

**Update 3:** corrected layout to match your added screenshots

```js
function toggle(e) {
  let o = document.getElementById("thing1")
  o.classList.toggle("opened");
}
```

```css
.SomeCustomNav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.SomeCustomNavRow {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.MiniContent {
  position: relative;
  border: dashed 1px grey;
}

.MiniContent.A {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.MiniContent.A.opened {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.MiniContent.B {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  height: 100px;
}

.CustomDropdownControl {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.text-and-dropdown {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.expandable-toolbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border: solid 1px #888;
}

#T {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0
}

.fakewrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}

.fake {
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<body>
  <div class="SomeCustomNav">
    <div class="SomeCustomNavRow">
      <div id="thing1" class="MiniContent A">
        <button id="T" type="button" onclick="toggle(event)">toggle</button>
        <div class="fakewrapper">
          <div class="fake">A</div>
          <div class="fake">B</div>
          <div class="fake">C</div>
          <div class="fake">D</div>
        </div>

        <div class="CustomDropdownControl">
          <div class="text-and-dropdown">
            <div class="input-group" style='z-index:9998;'>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="viewport" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style='z-index:9999;'>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="MiniContent B">Other stuff</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, this works for this limited example. But in reality, I need that input group and drop down inside the expandable toolbar.

Comment: Then you are going to have to move the dropdown html (not the button) outside that `overflow:hidden` div.  Maybe do a deep dive into the Popper.js parameters, I seem to recall something about a referenceObject that might offer some insight.

Comment: I am curious though.  What is an "Expandible toolbar" that doesn't expand?

Comment: Thanks @fnostro. This minimal example does not expand. But it uses the same overflow concept. I have modified the original question to provide a screenshot of the real world example. I hope that helps. Perhaps overflow hidden is not the right mechanism. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: In looking at this I did not get the layout quite right. But It's the end of the day here so I have to run. I hope there is enough here for you to figure this out.  I'll revisit this tomorrow to correct the layout and offer any other help.

Comment: Updated per above.